# dplyr is yielding lower sums, don't match sums in excel

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, aggregate-functions, summarize

I am using summarize in dplyr to add up individual data by household to see total of animals hunted per species per household. I'm noticing that the totals in the individual level data are higher, when they should be overall the same whether summed by individual or across all households.

```
>sp.echnops.h <-  df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(`HH ID`) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(x=sum(`Echnops (N Hunted)`, na.rm=TRUE))

# So this should equal 245 from the excel sheet, but equals 235

> sum(na.omit(sp.echnops.h$x))
```

[A sample of the data is found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dzbDYifW0e8H-S3s2uBSNFhtCBkCD_WNxlFNmaCbQ10/edit?usp=sharing)

> df$`HH ID`
> 1   1   1  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 101 101 102 102 102 102 102 104 104 105 105 105  11
> 11  11  11  12  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  14  14  14  14  14  14  15  15  15  15  15  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  17  17
> 17  17  17  17  18  18  18  18  18  19  19  19 106   2   2   2   2 106  23  23  24  24  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  26  27  27  27
> 27  28  28  28  28  28  29  29  29  29   3   3   3   3   3   3   3  30  30  32  32  32  36  36  36  36  36  37  37  37  37  37  38
> 38  38  38  39  39  39   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4  40  40  40  40  41  41  41  42  42  42  43  43  43  43  43  44  44  44
> 48  48  49  49  50  50  51  51  51  51  52  52  52  52  52  53  53  53  53  54  54  54  54  55  55  56  56  56  56  56  57  57  57
> 57  57  58  58  58  59  59   6   6   6   6   6  60  60  61  61  62  62  62  63  63  63  63  63  64  64  64  65  65  65  65  65  65
> 65  66  66  66  67  67  67  67  67  68  68  68  69  69  69  69  69   7   7   7   7  70  70  70  70  70  70  72  72  72  73  73  73
> 73  73  73  75  75  75  75  76  76  76  76  76  77  77  77  77  77  77  78  78  78  78  78  78   8   8   8   8   8   8  80  80  81
> 81  83  83  83  84  84  84  85  85  85  87  87  87  87  87  87  88  88  88  88  89  89  89   9   9   9   9  90  90  90  90  91  91
> 91  92  93  93  93  93  93  94  94  94  94  95  95  95  95  95  95  95  96  96  96  96  96  96  96  97  97  97  97  97  98  98  98
> 98  98  99  99  99  99

> df$`Echnops (N Hunted)`
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20  0  8  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  6 20  0  0  0  0  5  0
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10 NA  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
> 0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0 20
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0
> 0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0 NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
> 0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  6

Comment: A guess: `na.omit()` removes rows that have an `NA` anywhere in the whole row (in any column). You might be looking for `sum(sp.echnops.h$x, na.rm = TRUE)`, similar to what you use above, which only removes `NA` values in the column being summed.

Comment: If you need more help than that, please post your data reproducibly in the question, not as an external link--which requires downloading, importing, and code go bad at any time, reducing the long-term usefulness of the question. `dput()` is a great way to share data in a copy/pastaeable way, e.g., `dput(df[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. (Pick a suitable subset that illustrates the problem.)

Comment: In addition to Gregor's comments, maybe useful with `sum_` from `hablar` which will also make sure to return NA when there are all NA i.s. `summarise(x = sum_(`Echnops (N Hunted)`))`

Comment: Hi! Urgent help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to asking questions, and attempting to add in the data subset to the question - it might take me a second to get it right, and I apologize.

Comment: sum(sp.echnops.h$x, na.rm = TRUE) still yields 235. So I know that there are 245 total, but everything I aggregate it or summarize in dplyr, it's lower, and I've tried but can't figure out why.

Comment: @KatharineThompson i get 245 from your code i.e. `sum(na.omit(sp.echnops.h$x))
[1] 245#`

Comment: @KatharineThompson I am guessing that this may have something to do with how you read the data.  I downloaded as a csv and read with `df <- readr::read_csv(file.choose())`

Comment: @akrun I generally use df <- read_excel(...), does that cause errors?
I did all my analyses on these household level variables, and so I'm scared if the aggregated totals are lower than they actually are, then the analyses I did on these variables are all wrong. 

Also I'm sorry if I'm formatting things wrong on the question - I'm still learning and I'm SO SO grateful for help here.

Comment: @KatharineThompson Let me try with read-excel as well

Comment: I couldn't reproduce even with read_excel `df <- readxl::read_excel(file.choose())
                                                                                                                                                  
> sp.echnops.h <-  df %>%
+   dplyr::group_by(`HH ID`) %>%
+   dplyr::summarize(x=sum(`Echnops (N Hunted)`, na.rm=TRUE))
> sum(na.omit(sp.echnops.h$x))#
[1] 245`

Comment: Maybe check your package versions i.e. `packageVersion('readxl')#
[1] ‘1.3.1’`

Comment: @akrun I've used this syntax df <- read_excel("20210429.nf.xlsx")
I'm new to dplyr; would that cause errors?
I guess I'm wondering if I can trust my original aggregated variables or if they were likely wrong?

Comment: @KatharineThompson that would work fine.  I used `file.choose()` as I downloaded the excel into my Downloads and I didn't want to type the full path.  BTW, I tested this on `R 4.1.0` on a mac

Comment: @KatharineThompson as a check, can you confirm `sum(is.na(df[[2]]))#
[1] 4` 4 NAs in the original data

Comment: @akrun Thank you for all your help! I have a couple follow-up questions and stackeoverflow says I'm too new to start a private convo, would you mind starting a chat just so I can ask a couple more questions to better understand things?

Comment: @KatharineThompson can you join [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233200/question-d)

Comment: @akrun - apparently you also have to have at least 20 points to respond to a chat message, so I can enter the chat but stackoverflow won't let me reply. my email is katharine.thompson@stonybrook.edu; I'm so grateful for your help and sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: I tried to add you there, but it is having the same issue for write access

Comment: My daily vote limit passed, so i couldn't upvote you

Comment: Let me know if you'd be okay to chat via email; stackoverflow keeps telling me "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" but then doesn't let me chat or respond so I'm a bit stuck. Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if the variables I produced with my dplyr code were correct or wrong before changing the way I read the files, and if I should redo the subsequent analyses or not. So far when I rerun one of the analyses, the results are exactly the same (which would be good).

Comment: The issue is that I am able to read and get your expected ouptut 245, while something in your system is preventing it